# How to change the index of a dataframe after a function is applied in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have various `dataframes` named: step1, step2, step5, step7 and so on..

I wrote a function as follows:

```
def statistics(df):
    plus_one = df['BacksGas_Flow_sccm'][df['y_ocsvm'] == 1].describe()
    negative_one = df['BacksGas_Flow_sccm'][df['y_ocsvm'] == -1].describe()
    return plus_one, negative_one
```

where `BacksGas_Flow_sccm` & `y_ocsvm` are the names of column in all the different dataframes.

After this, I am trying to create a new dataframe that contains the statstical records returned by the `describe()` and I did that by:

```
stats = pd.DataFrame(statistics(step1))
stats = stats.append(pd.DataFrame(statistics(step2)))
```

and that gave me:

```
                    count          mean               std   min 25% 50% 75% max
BacksGas_Flow_sccm  1622.0  0.4370119194410199  0.11346778078574718 0.33333333333333304 0.33333333333333304 0.5 0.5 0.6666666666666665
BacksGas_Flow_sccm  426.0   0.19444444444444436 0.1873737774126198  0.0 0.16666666666666652 0.16666666666666652 0.16666666666666652 1.0
BacksGas_Flow_sccm  1285.0  0.5418071768266265  0.1998356616378414  0.2222222222222221  0.2222222222222221  0.6666666666666667  0.6666666666666667  0.6666666666666667
BacksGas_Flow_sccm  8028.0  0.4678901622100473  0.10157692912484724 0.0 0.4444444444444444  0.4444444444444444  0.5555555555555556  0.9999999999999998
```

I just want the index name to be changed from `BacksGas_Flow_sccm` to the corresponding dataframe they belong to

**Expected Output:**

```
         count         mean               std   min 25% 50% 75% max
Step1   1622.0  0.4370119194410199  0.11346778078574718 0.33333333333333304 0.33333333333333304 0.5 0.5 0.6666666666666665
Step1   426.0   0.19444444444444436 0.1873737774126198  0.0 0.16666666666666652 0.16666666666666652 0.16666666666666652 1.0
Step2   1285.0  0.5418071768266265  0.1998356616378414  0.2222222222222221  0.2222222222222221  0.6666666666666667  0.6666666666666667  0.6666666666666667
Step2   8028.0  0.4678901622100473  0.10157692912484724 0.0 0.4444444444444444  0.4444444444444444  0.5555555555555556  0.9999999999999998
```

I would like to know what can this be done.

thanks

Comment: having repeated index is not recommended, why not have it as a column?

Comment: That too is an option. Any suggestions about how can that can be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do so in `statistics` function, passing the name in:

```
def statistics(df, name):
    plus_one = df['BacksGas_Flow_sccm'][df['y_ocsvm'] == 1].describe()
    negative_one = df['BacksGas_Flow_sccm'][df['y_ocsvm'] == -1].describe()
    ret_df = pd.DataFrame((plus_one, negative_one))
    ret_df['source'] = name

    return ret_df

stats = pd.DataFrame(statistics(step1, 'step1'))
stats = stats.append(pd.DataFrame(statistics(step2, 'step2')))
```

Answer (score 1):

It's ugly but this should give you what you want without repeating indexes:

```
stats = pd.DataFrame(statistics(step1))
stats['step'] = 'Step1'
temp = pd.DataFrame(statistics(step2))
temp['step'] = 'Step2'
stats = stats.append(temp)
stats = stats.reset_index()
```